# python remove the empty line when input two parameters

Tags: python

When I use Spyder python 3.5 to set the input parameters as

```
n = int(input(""))
a = [int(x) for x in input("").split()]
```

However, It reveals as below when using the console

```
3

3 4 5
```

How can I do to remove the empty line and shows as

```
3
3 4 5
```

Comment: What shows that? You aren't printing anything. Are you sure the empty line isn't you hitting the enter key?

Comment: I want to reveal the inputs one by one without any empty lines

Comment: Can not reproduce. No empty line for me.

Comment: use print instead?